# Launch Firebird 1.5 installer from WIX

Tags: wix, firebird, installshield

I have been tasked with writing a WIX installer from an application that uses Firebird 1.5.  The WIX install process must launch the firebird installer if firebird has not already been installed. Using a custom action I get the firebird installer to launch but end up with error "1607 unable to install installshield scripting runtime".  I have searched this error but have not been able to find a resolution.
Here is a snipit of my custom action.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='LaunchFirebirdsetup' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id='LaunchFirebirdsetup' FileKey='Firebird15Setup' ExeCommand='' Return="ignore" Execute="commit" Impersonate="no" />
```

Comment: Did you see this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/888019 ?

Comment: As an aside: are you sure you still want to install Firebird 1.5, and not a more recent version like Firebird 2.5? Firebird 1.5 has been end-of-life for years and it hasn't been tested on Windows versions beyond XP (or maybe Vista).

Comment: Going to a later version would be ideal but is at this time out of my control. After this project, I may be able to convince them to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you cannot run an MSI install from within an MSI install, I think that's still true even with a Commit custom action. Your IS Script install is an MSI install, so that may be the issue. Launching installs from within installs is always an issue. You should use Burn to launch that Firebird install before installing yours. That's what a Burn bundle is for - prerequsites and associated installs as well as your MSI setup. You could use it to install a standalone ISScript MSI, that's another possibility.

The other issue is that some installs just don't work when installed with no impersonation, which means with the system account. There's no indication that you tried to do it silently, which means that it's running with the system account and may attempt to show UI to the interactive user, and that will fail. This another reason to install it with Burn - it will run as the interactive user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running an installer exe you could use merge modules. For instance the [Firebird 1.5 Merge Modules](http://www.mwasoftware.co.uk/download-msm-fb15/category/13-firebird-1-5-x) from MWA Software. Modules, [installation instruction](http://www.mwasoftware.co.uk/install-msm) and [source for the merge modules](http://www.mwasoftware.co.uk/download-msm/download/8-current-version/130-msm-build) are freely available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bootstrapping (burn) is the solution.
Took me a while to get it but after getting it to run, it makes sense I guess.